# Do we need dataset in each of the worker when using ParameterServerStrategy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, distributed, mlops

In the tutorial code of [ParameterServerTraining](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/distribute/parameter_server_training.ipynb#scrollTo=oMZ9Cu5J6ZGi) from tensorflow API, has the following snippet of code in `model.fit` section

```
def dataset_fn(input_context):
  global_batch_size = 64
  batch_size = input_context.get_per_replica_batch_size(global_batch_size)

  x = tf.random.uniform((10, 10))
  y = tf.random.uniform((10,))

  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).shuffle(10).repeat()
  dataset = dataset.shard(
      input_context.num_input_pipelines,
      input_context.input_pipeline_id)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
  dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)

  return dataset

dc = tf.keras.utils.experimental.DatasetCreator(dataset_fn)
```

and it's also said that

`The code in dataset_fn will be invoked on the input device, which is usually the CPU, on each of the worker machines.`

Does that mean the dataset must be on the same storage of every worker server (say the parameter server and the worker server are different machines)?

Or is there any way the parameter server on one machine can send the data for training to workers without the worker machines directly store the dataset here in ParameterServerStrategy that I don't understand?

Comment: (if anyone has the same doubt) Upon further study I found that, we can start a coordinator on 1 sever where parameter server are present and we can start  the workers and parameter ps using tf.distribute.Server(), which takes reduce calls or training calls from coordinator. check this link https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Server

Answer (score 0):

Answering here for the benefit of the community.

From the comment section:

> (if anyone has the same doubt) Upon further study I found that, we can
> start a coordinator on 1 sever where parameter server are present and
> we can start the workers and parameter ps using
> `tf.distribute.Server()`, which takes reduce calls or training calls
> from coordinator. check this link
> [tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Server](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Server)